# How does filtering in Shirabe Jisho work?

Tags: discussion

I’m trying to filter out uncommon words in my dictionary searches. Here I’m expecting to see 語, yet I’m getting the tag name in my results. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Shirabe Jisho iOS with the #common filter added, showing unexpected results.]